# How to register a custom control in Web.config file using powershell script

Tags: asp.net, powershell, web-config, custom-controls, nuget

When Nuget package for a custom control is installed, I want to register the control automatically inside the `<controls>` section of Web.config file.

I'm new to Powershell script. I want to add the following line inside the `<controls>` section of the Web.config file if it is not added already.

```
 <add namespace="SimpleCustomControl" assembly="SimpleCustomControl" tagPrefix="custom" />
```

I've added the followings scripts inside the `Install.ps1` file:

```
# Install.ps1
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

$xml = New-Object xml

# find the Web.config file
$config = $project.ProjectItems | where {$_.Name -eq "Web.config"}

# find its path on the file system
$localPath = $config.Properties | where {$_.Name -eq "LocalPath"}

# load Web.config as XML
$xml.Load($localPath.Value)

# Check whether the control is already registered
$node = $xml.SelectSingleNode("configuration/system.web/pages/controls[@namespace='SimpleCustomControl']")


# Not registered
if ($node -eq $null) {

# Register the custom control
$contrlsNode = $xml.SelectSingleNode("configuration/system.web/pages/controls")
# --> $contrlsNode.AddChild

} 

# save the Web.config file
$xml.Save($localPath.Value)
```

Can anyone please help me here?

Also is it possible to remove the custom control `<controls>` section from "Web.config" file when uninstalling the Nuget package? If so, what is the powershell script to do so inside `Uninstall.ps1` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you already figured out everything, but adding and removing nodes.

To append your new XML node, do something like this:

```
$parentNode = $xml.SelectSingleNode("system.web/pages")

$childNode = $xml.CreateElement("add")
$childNode.SetAttribute("namespace", "SimpleCustomControl")
$childNode.SetAttribute("assembly", "SimpleCustomControl")
$childNode.SetAttribute("tagPrefix", "custom")

$parentNode.AppendChild($childNode)
```

This will create a new node, set the attributes and finally append it to the parent node.

To remove the node, find it using the same `SelectSingleNode()` XPath expression as you used in your sample, then

```
$node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($node)
```

This is a bit awkward, but as you cannot remove the node itself, you need to find its parent (`.ParentNode`) and remove this specific child (`$node`).